# how can i edit the contents or the styles of a reused (reusable) component without changing the other in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a component called search-footer component which i am using as a search bar and as a footer, i want to change a bit of the content and styles of the footer without affecting the search-bar how can i achieve this?

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-search-footer></app-search-footer> //this needes content and styles updating
```

i use the search-footer component inside the navbar component and in my HomeComponent as you can see

Comment: A simple solution would be to conditionally apply inline style or a class based on an input variable.

Comment: @GunnarB. would you be so kind to provide any example thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. use `Input` to control this like

```ts
<app-search-footer version='search'></app-search-footer>
```

In the component:

```
@Input() version: 'search' | 'footer' = 'footer';
```

In the component template at the respective spots:

```
class="some-element {{version}}"
```

In the css (scss in this case) e.g.:

```css
.some-element {
  &.search {
    background-color: red;
  }

  &.footer {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

How to best do this of course also depends on what needs to be changed (like if it is the whole component or very specific parts of it).
If it is the whole component, you could also simply do `<app-search-footer class='search'></app-search-footer>`.

There are quite a few ways to accomplish things like this before having to rely on `:host ::ngdeep`.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can update the styles of the child component via the parent component using the following,

- The `::ng-deep` pseudo-class. As applying it to any CSS rule completely disabled view-encapsulation for that rule. In order to scope the specified style to current component and its descendants, add the `:host` selector before `::ng-deep`, as without it the applied styles can bleed to other components.
- Applying `ViewEncapsulation.None` inside the component in which the child component is being loaded.

Therefore using the above mentioned approaches, you can modify the styles for `app-search-footer` as shown in the code snippets below,

- Using the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class,

In the file component.css,

```css
::host ::ng-deep app-search-footer {
  /* Add required CSS rules */
}
```

- Using `ViewEncapsulation.None`

In the file component.ts,

```js
import {
  Component,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: '<div class="container"><app-search-footer></app-search-footer></div>',
      styleUrls: ['`.container .app-search-footer-container { /* Required CSS rules */ }`'],
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
      }) 
export class Component implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also if you want to change the data in only one component without affecting the other one you can also use *@Input* decoratos to achieve that

[image: app-search-footer]

this is my search panel <app-search-footer> which im going to use also as a footer but with a little bit of tweaks

[image: also]

this is also my <app-search-footer> component but here im using it as a footer and as you can see from the image, i added a horizontal rule new logo image and three new paragraphs (Terms os Use, Privacy Policy and About Us) i did this by adding these Input() variables in my search-footer component.ts file

```
@Input() termsOfUse = '';
@Input() privacyPolicy = '';
@Input() aboutUs = '';
@Input() hr: boolean = false;
@Input() footerImage = '';
```

in my html file i added these

```
<img src="{{footerImage}}" class="brand" alt="">
<hr style="color: #ffffff;" *ngIf="hr">
<p class="footer-pargraphs">{{termsOfUse}}</p>
<p class="footer-pargraphs">{{privacyPolicy}}</p>
<p class="footer-pargraphs">{{aboutUs}}</p>
```

when i reused this component as footer i just binded my data to the inputs of the search-footer component like so

```
<app-search-footer [termsOfUse]="'Terms of Use'" [hr]=true [footerImage]="'assets/download.png'" [privacyPolicy]='"Privacy Policy"' [aboutUs]="'About us'" *ngIf="!collapsed" ></app-search-footer>
```

and i was able to modify the footer without affecting my search panel.
The one downside to this is that in your base component (search-footer in my case) there will be elements with empty values and therefore will be empty space in your DOM.